# How to get files uploaded on FTP server with React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

Actually, I want to get the files with directory structure uploaded on FTP server using React-native.

I have tried to find libraries but I didn't find anything related to it.

So can you please help me with this problem?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import FTP from 'react-native-ftp';

export default class App extends Component {
  onButtonpress() {
     FTP.setup("IP", 21) //Setup host
     FTP.login("username", "password").then(
     (result) => {
        FTP.list(".").then(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }
      );
    },
   (error) => {
    alert(error);
   }
  )
}
render() {
  return (
    <View >
      <Button onPress={this.onButtonpress.bind(this)} title="hi" />
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Here is the sample i have tried but i got error while impoting 'react-native-ftp'.
I got error "Could not find declaration for module 'react-native-ftp'".

Comment: have tried react-native-ftp

Comment: if yes then please put some code around that you have tried! please

Comment: I have attached my code. Please help me to find solution.

Comment: its for logging into the server of ftp that you have done so  far! now go for something like 

react-native-file-transfer please and reply if that helps somehow

Comment: I have tried "react-native-ftp" in Android and it is working fine but it is not working in iOS.

Comment: are you testing it on a real device? and are you having the log or any warning or something?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it on a real device and I haven't got any warning or error.

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve your iOS problem with react-native-ftp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you encounter is because of react-native-ftp  functions are not available on ios - they are not implemented. You need to fork the repo and implement them to work with ios too.

and then:
You can download a file like below using react-native-ftp:

```
FTP.downloadFile("./nameOfFileToBeDownloaded","localPathWhereItWillBeSaved")
    .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(error=>alert(error))
```

Or upload with uploadFile:

```
FTP.uploadFile("./nameOfFileToBeUploaded","remotePathWhereItWillBeSaved")
    .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(error=>alert(error))
```

If you want entire folder, you can zip it first with [react-native-zip-archive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zip-archive) and the upload just the zip.

Comment: hey I got this error when uploading file : 
[Error: ./file/test.gif: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)]